# How to create a CDI Interceptor which advises methods from a Feign client?

Tags: cdi, interceptor, feign

I've been trying to figure out how to intercept methods defined in a Feign client with CDI (1.2) interceptors. I need to intercept the response value the client is returning, and extract data to log and remove some data prior to it being returned to the calling process.

I'm running a Weld 2.3 container which provides CDI 1.2.  In it, I would like to create a CDI interceptor which is triggered everytime a call to `filter()` is made.

```
public interface MyRepository {
    @RequestLine("POST /v1/data/policy/input_data_filtered")
    JsonNode filter(Body body);
}
```

and a matching Producer method:

```
@Produces
public MyRepository repositoryProducer() {
    return Feign.builder()
            .client(new ApacheHttpClient())
            .encoder(new JacksonEncoder(mapper))
            .decoder(new JacksonDecoder(mapper))
            .logger(new Slf4jLogger(MyRepository.class))
            .logLevel(feign.Logger.Level.FULL)
            .target(MyRepository.class,  "http://localhost:9999");
}
```

I've tried the standard CDI interceptor way by creating an `@InterceptorBinding` and adding it to the interface definition, but that didn't work.  I suspect because the interceptor must be applied to the CDI bean(proxy) and cannot be defined in an interface.   I tried applying it to the `repositoryProducer()` method but that too was non functional.

I've read about the `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InterceptionFactory` which is availabel in CDI 2.0, but I don't have access to it.

How can I do this in CDI 1.2?  Or alternatively, is there a better interceptor pattern I can use that is built into Feign somehow?

Comment: I don't know Feign, but I the builder you showed in your post does probably not create the underlying object via the CDI container. In this case, it is simply not possible, as you only can intercept CDI business methods. Maybe have a look at AOP?

Comment: @mtj The Producer adds the bean to the container and provides the Proxy object on it.  With no scope defined, it should be a `@Dependent` bean.  The issue is that the container doesn't know that I want an interceptor around it, and I'm not sure how to do this with CDI 1.2

Answer (score 2):

The short, somewhat incorrect answer is: you cannot.  `InterceptionFactory` is indeed how you would do it if you could.

The longer answer is something like this:

1. Use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` to create a proxy implementation of the `MyRepository` interface.
2. Create an `InvocationHandler` that performs the interception around whatever methods you want.
3. Target Feign at that proxy implementation.

Comment: I  was afraid that was the solution; something more complicated than I wanted to try.  Might just use AspectJ instead as it will be much more easily read & understood for maintainability.  I was hoping to avoid adding AJ dependency to this project though.